# NestjS - Swagger ui css resource not found in production mode

Tags: css, express, swagger-ui, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am working on a nestjs project, I've added swagger to display my endpoints, It's working great in dev mode, but once deployed in production using https://zeit.co/ (now), the endpoints page is not displayed correctly (the css is missing), I got in the network tab this error:

```
/favicon-32x32.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/favicon-16x16.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
swagger-ui.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9IQv.png

Thanks.

Comment: More information is needed.  It is likely that webpack (or whatever bundler you are using) is not including the CSS file.  This is likely due to the way you are importing the CSS file or swagger-ui package.  As I recall from my last experience with swagger-ui, by default you don't need to manually include CSS files at all.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I am using nestjs with swagger: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger, It works great in Dev, but not in Prod

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zeit.co`.  How are you deploying to prod?  Is the process different than how you deploy to dev?  By dev do you mean running locally, or do you deploy to an actual dev server?

Comment: For zeit.com, I just discover it using this article:https://trilon.io/blog/deploying-nestjs-to-zeit-now, by dev I mean running the project locally in localhost:3000

Comment: I was able to make it work with a little workaround, by getting the content of swagger-ui.css and create a file with its content, put it in a public folder and then serve static using this link: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static#serve-static

Comment: did you found solution ?
i have same issue

Comment: Yes with a little workaround, check my previous response

Comment: @YounessHoudass Can you post a link to an example? I did the serve-static thing but keeps failing in prod :(

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide additional options in **SwaggerModule.setup** method:

```js
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';

// some code...

const options = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('Your title')
  .setDescription('Your description')
  .setVersion('1.0')
  .build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document, {
  customCssUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui.min.css',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add custom css & js files like this:

```js
SwaggerModule.setup('/swagger', app, swaggerDocument, {
    customCssUrl:
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui.min.css',
    customJs: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing what @Manuchhehr suggested, the css/js loaded correctly but the url paths were slightly distorted,
as displayed in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rumNT.png

had to add customCss to solve it,

```js
SwaggerModule.setup('/swagger', app, swaggerDocument, {
     customCss:
      '.swagger-ui .opblock .opblock-summary-path-description-wrapper { align-items: center; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 0 10px; padding: 0 10px; width: 100%; }',
    customCssUrl:
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui.min.css',
    customJs: [
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.15.5/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
    ],
});
```

hope it helps...